# Error in importing export_text from sklearn.tree.export

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have a decision tree classifier and while importing export_text from sklearn.tree.export I am getting error as below ,

ImportError: cannot import name 'export_text' from 'sklearn.tree.export' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\export.py)

Is there any way to resolve this

I have tried with the code mentioned in the [documentation](https://scikit-earn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_text.html), as below:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.tree.export import export_text
iris = load_iris()
X = iris['data']
y = iris['target']
decision_tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0, max_depth=2)
decision_tree = decision_tree.fit(X, y)
r = export_text(decision_tree, feature_names=iris['feature_names'])
print(r)
|--- petal width (cm) <= 0.80
|   |--- class: 0
|--- petal width (cm) >  0.80
|   |--- petal width (cm) <= 1.75
|   |   |--- class: 1
|   |--- petal width (cm) >  1.75
|   |   |--- class: 2
```

I am using my python-3.7.3 and other associated libraries version as

```
import sklearn
import numpy
import scipy
import joblib
print(sklearn.__version__)    == > 0.20.3
print(numpy.__version__)      === > 1.16.2
print(scipy.__version__)      ==>   1.2.1
print(joblib.__version__)     ==>  0.13.2
```

Error as below :

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'export_text' from 'sklearn.tree.export' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\export.py)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is just

```
from scikit.tree import export_text
```

Answer (score 1):

`from sklearn.tree import export_text`

instead of

`from sklearn.tree.export import export_text`

it works for me.

The issue is with the sklearn version.

[here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_text.html)

Answer (score -1):

The issue is with the sklearn version.

Updated sklearn would solve this.

sklearn.**version**  of 0.21.3 will resolve this.

Any other method/code to print as requested except using sklearn.